# Matlab Neural Network Weights

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

In Matlab I ran the neural networks toolbox and received weights titled the following:

```
    b1 = {...};
    IW1_1 = {...};

    b2 = {...};
    LW2_2 = {...};
```

What part of the neural network are these weights referring to? I'm assuming b1 and b2 are the biases and IW1_1 and LW2_2 are the weights, but what part of the network is IW1_1 for and LW2_2 for?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Do you know what part of the network IW1_1 is for and LW2_2 is for?

Comment: IW is the input layer. LW are the hidden layers that follow. Try the separatewb function to help distinguish what weights are what. http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/separatewb.html

Answer (score 0):

IW1_1 is the weights between the input and hidden layers and LW2_2 is between the hidden and output layers.